# How to override uc_cart_checkout_form()?

Tags: 7, hooks, ubercart

Is there a hook_checkout_form of some sort?

How can I alter uc_cart_checkout_form()? The function itself located in uc_cart.pages.inc and not the form. As I can just do this with hook_form_alter.

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: `hook_form_alter` is the way to alter any form built with the API (which `uc_cart_checkout_form` is). There won't be a specific hook for that one form because it would be a duplication of existing functionality. Maybe you're looking for [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)?

Comment: Can I manipulate order $_sessions using hook_form_alter?

Comment: `$_SESSION` is a global array so you can access it from anywhere. No idea if that makes sense in the context of a checkout form I'm afraid